# Error reading an element twice in the same unix socket connection

Tags: c++, ruby, sockets, unix-socket

I am facing a rather strange problem. I have created a unix socket server between ruby and C where, on the C side, a main thread creates and listens to the socket and, upon accept or a connection, lets a thread (from a thread pool) perform the reading and processing of the information.

I am seeing that whenever I have high load my accept() accepts 2 or 3 times the same connection. This is usually accompanied with the client throwing on me a "broken pipe" message on the connection that should actually had been sent.

For example:

client:

```
Sending 1
Sending 2
Sending 3
Error is Broken pipe
Sending 4
Sending 5
...
```

server:

```
New connection is 1
New connection is 2
New connection is 2 <<<< this should not be here!
New connection is 4
New connection is 5
New connection is 6
```

My code is (C++ code, server)

```
//(... create the socket with standard socket, bind and listen calls)
while(1) {
        // Wait for connection
        int connection = accept(streamSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clilen);
        if (connection < 0){
            LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to accept new client socket connection, request index = " << requests;
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("New connection is %d\n", connection);

        // Add connection to handler thread in pool
        pool.AddJob([this, connection, requests, streamSocket]() {
            char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
            bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            int n = read(connection, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1);

            //(... processing of the info)
        }
        close(connection);
        });
    }
```

And the client side in ruby (run within a loop):

```
request = "whatever json"
for count in 1..10
  begin
    puts "Sending #{count}"
    socket = UNIXSocket.new("/tmp/mysocket.socket")
    socket.puts(request)
    response = socket.read
    socket.close
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Error is #{e}"
  end
end
```

**Update**

I have see that using socket.send or socket.write instead of socket.puts I do not get any "broken pipe" errors and therefore there are no repeated accepts in the C side. Still, I have checked online and the only (aparent) difference between them seems to be that socket.puts adds a newline at the end of the message. I would like to know why puts does not work and which one (send or write) is recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

```
New connection is 2
<--- You probably have closed connection 2 here. Double check your code
New connection is 2 <<<< this should not be here!
```

When the client writes to a connection has been closed by the server, it will trigger a `Broken pipe` signal.